# How to document small changes to complex API functions?

Tags: python, documentation

Let's say we have a complex API function, imported from some library.

```
def complex_api_function(
        number, <lots of positional arguments>,
        <lots of keyword arguments>):
    '''really long docstring'''
    # lots of code
```

I want to write a simple wrapper around that function to make a tiny change. **For example**, it should be possible to pass the first argument as a string. How to document this? I considered the following options:

#### Option 1:

```
def my_complex_api_function(number_or_str, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    Do something complex.

    Like `complex_api_function`, but first argument can be a string.

    Parameters
    ----------
    number_or_str : int or float or str
        Can be a number or a string that can be interpreted as a float.
        <copy paste description from complex_api_function docstring>
    *args
        Positional arguments passed to `complex_api_function`.
    **kwargs
        Keyword arguments passed to `complex_api_function`.

    Returns
    -------
    <copy paste from complex_api_function docstring>

    Examples
    --------
    <example where first argument is a string, e.g. '-5.0'>

    '''
    return complex_api_function(float(number_or_str), *args, **kwargs)
```

Disadvantage: User has to look at the docs of `complex_api_function` to get
information about `*args` and `**kwargs`. Needs adjustment when the copy pasted sections from `complex_api_function` change.

#### Option 2:

Copy and paste `complex_api_function`'s signature (instead of using `*args` and `**kwargs`) and its docstring. Make a tiny change to the docstring that mentions that the first argument can also be a string. Add an example.

Disadvantage: verbose, has to be changed when `complex_api_function` changes.

#### Option 3:

Decorate `my_complex_api_function` with `functools.wraps(complex_api_function)`.

Disadvantage: There's no information that `number` can also be a string.

---

I'm looking for an answer that does not hinge on the details of what changes in `my_complex_api_function`. The procedure should work for any tiny adjustment to the original `complex_api_function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend something like the following:

```py
def my_complex_api_function(number_or_str, *args, **kwargs):
    """This function is a light wrapper to `complex_api_function`.
    It allows you to pass a string or a number, whereas `complex_api_function` requires a 
    number. See :ref:`complex_api_function` for more details.

    :param number_or_str: number or str to convert to a number and pass to `complex_api_function`.
    :param args: Arguments to pass to `complex_api_function`
    :param kwargs: Keyword arguments to pass to `complex_api_function`
    :return: Output of `complex_api_function`, called with passed parameters
    """
```

This is clear and concise. But please also remember that, if using a documentation system like sphinx, to link the functions with `` :ref:`bob` `` or similar.

Comment: I would not even mention what type `complex_api_function` expects for its parameter since that just duplicates information (maybe they have multiple options too). Presumably the user of the wrapper is already familiar with the original function and if not you can always point them to the original docs. Anyway I think this is the way to go, only document what is *added* to the original function + providing details about how that new type gets converted to the original one (those details might be important). I.e. how that argument is treated in order to be compatible with the original function.

Comment: That's a good point on linking - I've added an edit for a `:ref:` in the docstring. However, for *small* api changes - as the OP is asking about - it allows users to compare the functions more simply. In this case the minimal effort might give that little bit more gain to end users - and when I read docs, I'd take a 12 page doc over a 6 page doc in most cases, because it's that little be easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

You could automate the "specialization" of the original docstring with an *addendum*. For instance, [*pydoc*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) is using [the special attribute `__doc__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id15). You could write a decorator which automatically overrides the original function `__doc__` with your addendum.

For instance:

```py
def extend_docstring(original, addendum):
    def callable(func):
        func.__doc__ = original + addendum
        return func

    return callable


def complex_api_function(a, b, c):
    '''
    This is a very complex function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a: int or float
        This is the argument A.
    b: ....
    '''
    print('do something')

@extend_docstring(
    complex_api_function.__doc__,
    '''
    Addendum
    --------
    Parameter a can also be a string
    '''
)
def my_complex_api_function(a, b, c):
    return complex_api_function(float(a), b, c)
```

or...

```py
def extend_docstring(original):
    def callable(func):
        func.__doc__ = original + func.__doc__
        return func

    return callable


def complex_api_function(a, b, c):
    '''
    This is a very complex function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a: int or float
        This is the argument A.
    b: ....
    '''
    print('do something')

@extend_docstring(complex_api_function.__doc__)
def my_complex_api_function(a, b, c):
    '''
    Addendum
    --------
    Parameter a can also be a string
    '''
    return complex_api_function(float(a), b, c)
```

If you run *pydoc* (`pydoc3 -w my_module.py`) it produces: [preview of html generated by pydoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy67d.png)

Additional note:
If you are using Python 3 you could use [annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) to document the type(s) of your function parameters. It offers a lot of benefits, not only documentation. For instance:

```py
from typing import Union

def my_complex_api_function(number_or_str: Union[int, float, str], *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage that the important (new) information is "hidden" at the end of the (presumably very long) doc string. Hence discoverability of the new feature is very low while it is the only valuable information that adds to the existing doc string. In addition it conflicts type declarations on the original doc string. That is if the user looks at the extended doc string, they will see `a : float` at the very top and never come to the conclusion that they might also use a `str` here. Only if by chance they scroll to the very end of the docs they'll discover it.

Comment: You could add the addendum at the beginning instead of the end... Like a "revision" note at the beginning of a document.

Comment: Another issue is the duplication (+ freezing) of information. Let's say you build a package that ships this wrapper and you specify your dependencies as `complex_package >= 1.1.0`. Now when you build your package, you have to use one specific version for `complex_package`. Let's say there exists already `complex_package==1.5.0` on pypi and they added a new keyword argument to `complex_api_function` in version `1.3.0`. Either way (using `1.1.0` or `1.5.0`) you'll have outdated/wrong information for a subgroup of your users in the doc. The same applies to future changes that are not yet public.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it helps avoid the question entirely.

```
def first_as_num_or_str(func):
    '''Decorator allowing the first parameter of the given function to be a number or a string

    :param func: A function whose first argument is a number
    :return: `func`, but now the first argument is cast to a float
    ''' 
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        func(float(args[0]), args[1:], kwargs)
    return new_func

wrapped_api_func = first_as_num_or_str(complex_api_function)
```

Comment: Thank you. `wrapped_api_func` has no docstring, so the documentation issue is not solved.